# Convert http to https on save

Tags: hooks, input-formats, ssl

While migrating our site, we have put them on 'SSL required'.

How can we best force, when editors save datas containing http link, a conversion to https ( or //).

Comment: are you asking about converting values during your migration or are you asking about what to do moving forward on the site? I assume that later... If  so, are you asking about a link field or are you asking about a text field (like "body") that might contain a link? If its the later, are you using a rich text toolbar?

Comment: once migrated yes. on any fields of any content types that are editable.I amusing ckeditor. I believe i have to create a custom format filter ?

Comment: Is this something Pathologic can solve https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a module with a custom text format filter :

```
function my_module_filter_info() {  
   $filters ['to_https_compatible_converter'] = array (
        'title' => t ( 'HTTPS compatible convertible filter' ),
        'description' => t ( 'convert http:// to // for https  compatiblity' ),
        'process callback' => '_module_filter_process',
        'tips callback' => '_module_filter_tips' 
   );   
  return $filters;
 }




 function _module_filter_tips($filter, $format, $long = FALSE) {
switch ($filter->name) {        
    case 'to_https_compatible_converter' :
        return t ( 'convert http:// to // for https  compatiblity' );   
}
    }

  function _module_filter_process($text, $filter) { 
      switch ($filter->name) {      
    case 'to_https_compatible_converter' :

        $dom = new DOMDocument ();
        @$dom->loadHTML ( utf8_decode ( $text ) );

        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName ( 'img' );
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            $image_src = $image->getAttribute ( 'src' );
            $image_src=str_replace(['http://','https://'],'//',$image_src);             
            $image->setAttribute ( 'src' ,$image_src);

        }

        $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName ( 'a' );
        foreach ( $links as $link ) {
            $href = $link->getAttribute ( 'href' );
            $href=str_replace(['http://','https://'],'//',$href);       
            $link->setAttribute ( 'href' ,$href);

        }

        $iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName ( 'iframe' );
        foreach ( $iframes as $iframe ) {
            $src = $iframe->getAttribute ( 'src' );
            $src=str_replace(['http://','https://'],'//',$src);         
            $iframe->setAttribute ( 'src' ,$src);           
        }

        return $dom->saveHTML ();

}
 }
```